# return array of #NA

Tags: arrays, excel, vba

I have a list of item numbers.Some of them don't have details associated with them. I would like the list of item numbers that don't have info associated. they can be identified with #N/A error. 
I'm running excel 2007.

i am using this array formula to return the associated details. which are in column A
=IF(ISERROR(VLOOKUP(J12,A:H,{2,3,4,5,6,7,8},FALSE)),"",VLOOKUP(J12,A:H,{2,3,4,5,6,7,8},FALSE))

if the lookup can't find the associated item number in column a it returns blanks, otherwise it returns the associated data.

the ones that error, i need a list of those.

is there a formula or a vba macro to get this information?
thanks for your time
Ian

Comment: I don't understand your use of the array constant here, i.e. {2,3,4,5,6,7,8}. As it stands, that formula can only ever return a result from column B, so referencing the other 6 columns is completely redundant.

Answer (score 0):

As XORLX said: why you are using `{values}` as its picking items from column B?

Anyway you can change your formula with

```
=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(J12,A:H,{2,3,4,5,6,7,8},FALSE),"N/A")
```

So in case of error it will give N/A which you can later filter.

But I think you want result as in this pic 
[Sample File](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FESwG.jpg)
Where
K6=IFERROR(INDEX(A:H,MATCH(J6,A:A,0),(IF(INDIRECT("B"&MATCH(J6,A:A,0))<>"",2,IF(INDIRECT("C"&MATCH(J6,A:A,0))<>"",3,IF(INDIRECT("D"&MATCH(J6,A:A,0))<>"",4,IF(INDIRECT("E"&MATCH(J6,A:A,0))<>"",5,IF(INDIRECT("F"&MATCH(J6,A:A,0))<>"",6,IF(INDIRECT("G"&MATCH(J6,A:A,0))<>"",7,IF(INDIRECT("H"&MATCH(J6,A:A,0))<>"",8))))))))),"N/A")
In my example I am looking for Joy which is in Row 2.
Now after finding Row 2 it will go and check 2nd Column B which is empty so it will go for 3rd C and so on and when will return the data from the 1st column and if find nothing then will return error.

Comment: ok let's define the problem better. I have 2 lists. The first is the original non contiguous list with associated data in columns b - h.  The second list is the contiguous list of item numbers.  I use the second list as the target to match. I search for the match In the first list.  If it's there I want the formula to return b-h in k-r. Then based on that I want a 3rd list of all the ones that weren't found. Is that clearer?

Comment: There are no blank spots in a-h the list is in numeric order. It just skips over the ones that aren't there.  I don't want the output in one cell. It's faster using a formula than copy paste especially when there are 100,000 rows. So look for the value in column j and return b-h in k-r if found. Does that make sense?